# how do you change to laravel syntax?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have an SQL query below which I want to change to Laravel Eloquent or Query Builder.

```
$myDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime( date( "Y-m-d", strtotime( date("Y-m-d") ) ) . "+1 month" ) );


$result = mysql_query( 'SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE expire_date BETWEEN NOW AND "' . $myDate . '"' );
```

Please, help me!

Comment: This is too broad a question. Also, Laravel accepts raw PHP code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do something like this:

Assuming that `myTable` has a model called `MyTable`:

```php
$now = Carbon::now();
$nowPlus1Month = Carbon::now()->addMonth();
//If you want to sub a month:
$nowMinusMonth = Carbon::now()->subMonth();

$result = MyTable::whereBetween('expire_date', [$now, $nowPlus1Month])->get();

// Or
$result = MyTable::whereBetween('expire_date', [$nowMinusMonth, $now])->get();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: how about 1 month before today?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
 $now = Carbon::now();
 $nowPlus1Month = Carbon::now()->addMonth();

 $result = MyTable::whereBetween('expire_date', [$now, $nowPlus1Month])->get();
 //Substract 1 month from the date
 $result = MyTable::whereBetween('expire_date', [$now, Carbon::now()->subDays(30)])->get();
```